# How to allow non-unique column names in PgfPlotsTable?

Tags: pgfplotstable, csv, combine

I have been struggling with PgfPlotsTable for a while. Problem is that I cannot get rid of '-indexNum' appended at the end of my column names. Does anyone know if there's an option to have non-unique column names? I've gone over PgfPlots manual but I can't find anything. I also tried renaming columns but didn't work either. By the way, I am reading all these values from a CSV file.

This is how the code for my table looks like:

```
\begin{table}[ht!]
\begin{center}
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
        \pgfplotstabletypeset[
            col sep=comma,
            string type,
            assign column name/.style={/pgfplots/table/column name={\textbf{#1}}},
            every column/.code={
                \ifnum\pgfplotstablecol>0
                    \pgfkeysalso{column type/.add={|}{}}
                \fi
            },
            assign column name/.style={/pgfplots/table/column name={#1}},
            every head row/.style={after row=\hline, before row=\hline \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{MLR}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Ridge}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Lasso}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Elastic Net}} \\ \hline},
            every last row/.style={after row=\hline}
            ]{resources/athletes_cv.csv}
    }
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Bonus: does anyone know how to merge two cells? So that Athlete takes all the space? This is denoted by the arrow in the embedded picture.

This is how the output looks like:

[image: Table from PgfPlotsTable]

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! Please post a complete example that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` and include some sample csv file.

Comment: Note that `colname`  and `column name` are not the same.  The colname is a unique identified (probably used in \csname) whereas the column name is what is shown when the table is typeset.  In this case you might be better simply to use [header=false] and store the first row as data (string type).